# $a$, $n$ are relatively prime iff least significant digit of representation $(a)_{n}$ base n is relatively prime to n

Tags: number-theory

Please can someone help me with this:

Prove that $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime iff $a_{0}$ is relatively prime to n, where 
$a_{0}$ is the last digit of the representation $a_{n}$ base $n$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_0$
is the "units" digit
in base $n$,
then
$a
=a_dn^d+a_{d-1}n^{d-1}+...+a_1n+a_0
=n(a_dn^{d-1}+a_{d-1}n^{d-2}+...+a_1)+a_0
=nA+a_0
$
where
$A
=a_dn^{d-1}+a_{d-1}n^{d-2}+...+a_1
$.

Therefore
$a-a_0
=nA
$.

You should be able to
do the rest.